# IOMeter doesn't write log files due to full disk

Tags: testing, logging, io, automation, solid-state-drive

Does anyone have a workaround for IOMeter not writing logs to disk? I believe this is because the iobw.tst file takes up the whole disk. I have had the test running, then manually created a temporary 1MB file while the disk was filling up, then deleted that 1MB file after the disk is full and while the reads and writes are being performed and this consistently produces the full log file for the test. Similarly, clearing the Recycle Bin or temporary files at this time produces the same result.

Does anyone know of a way to reserve this space for the logfile using a configuration file or something along these lines? IOMeter is part of an automated suite of tests that I'm working on and this issue is preventing full automation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile Dynamo with "DETAILS" and/or "DEBUG" flags "on".

Then dynamo will store all the info into ~/std.out log (if you're under linux)